# Spring Batch reading and writng only 2 chunks after that getting stuck

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-batch

I am reading a CSV file and writing into another csv file using FlatItemReader and FlatItemWriter in Spring batch.
It is reading and writing for first 2 chunks and after it gets stuck in sempahre.acquire(), going in infinite loop and stuck.
I am using simpleJob Launcher for launching job and using DatasourceTransactionManager

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(createJobRepository());
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }

    private JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
        factory.setValidateTransactionState(false);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate(ApplicationFlowConstants.DB_READ_ISOLATION_LEVEL);
        factory.setDatabaseType(ApplicationFlowConstants.ORACLE);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

below job executing

```
@Component
public class DataloaderBatchExecutor {
    private static final ILogger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataloaderBatchExecutor.class);

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("simpleJobLauncher")
    private SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pdadLoaderJob")
    Job pdadLoaderJob;

    public DataLoaderJobRequest executeJob(DataLoaderJobRequest request, Job jobToExecute)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
            JobParametersInvalidException {
        JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameterBuilder(request);
        try {
            
            JobExecution execution = simpleJobLauncher.run(pdadLoaderJob, jobParameters);
            LOGGER.info("STATUS---{}",execution.getStatus());

            if (!BatchStatus.COMPLETED.equals(execution.getStatus())) {
                throwExceptionOnFailedBatch(execution); 
            } 
            
            int totalRecordsProcessed = execution.getStepExecutions().stream()
                    .mapToInt(StepExecution::getWriteCount).sum();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        //  request.setBatchJobStatus(execution.getStatus().name());
        //  request.setNoOfItemProcessed(totalRecordsProcessed);
        return request;
    }

    private void throwExceptionOnFailedBatch(JobExecution execution) {
        String errorMessage = execution.getAllFailureExceptions()
                .stream()
                .map(Throwables::getStackTraceAsString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        ExceptionCode exceptionCode = new ExceptionCode(
                "FileToload Spring Job failed", errorMessage);
        throw new DISystemException(exceptionCode);
    }

    private JobParameters getJobParameterBuilder(DataLoaderJobRequest request) {
        return new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(ApplicationFlowConstants.INPUT_FILE_PATH, request.getFile().getPath())
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                //.addString("INPUT_FILE_NAME", "")
                // .addString(INPUT_DATA_FILE_FIELD_MAPPING_FILE_PATH, fieldMappingDirPath + fileDataNature.getFieldMappingFileName())
                .toJobParameters();

    }

}
```

Job configuration

```
@Configuration
public class PdadDataloaderJob {

    private Resource outputResource = new FileSystemResource("output/outputData.csv");
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<PdadModel> pdadFileReader(
            @Value(ApplicationFlowConstants.JOB_PARAM_INPUT_FILE_PATH) final String filepath) {

        FlatFileItemReader<PdadModel> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PdadModel>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new PathResource(filepath));
        return itemReader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<PdadModel, PdadModel> processor() {
        return new PdadProcessors();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<PdadModel> pdadWriter(){
        System.out.println("Inside Writer");
        //NoOpItemWriter writer = new NoOpItemWriter(); 


        //Create writer instance

        FlatFileItemWriter<PdadModel> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

        //Set output file location 
        writer.setResource(outputResource);

        //All job repetitions should "append" to same output file
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

        //Name field values sequence based on object properties
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<PdadModel>() { {
            setDelimiter(","); 
            setFieldExtractor(new
                    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<PdadModel>() { 
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" }); 
                } 
                }); 
            } });

        return writer;

    }

    @Bean
    public Job pdadLoaderJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step stepsLoadPdadFile) {
        return jobs.get("pdadLoaderJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(new JobResultListener())
                //.listener((JobExecutionListener) new CustomChunkListener())
                //.listener((JobExecutionListener) new StepItemReadListener())
                //.listener((JobExecutionListener) new StepItemProcessListener())
                //.listener((JobExecutionListener) new StepItemWriteListener())
                .flow(stepsLoadPdadFile).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepsLoadPdadFile(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemReader<PdadModel> pdadFileReader,
            ItemProcessor<PdadModel, PdadModel> pdadProcessor,
            ItemWriter<PdadModel> pdadWriter) {
        // int chunkSize = env.getProperty(ApplicationFlowConstants.BATCH_CHUNK_SIZE, Integer.class, 100);
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("stepsLoadPdadFile")
                
                //.listener(new StepItemReadListener())
                //.listener(new StepItemProcessListener())
                //.listener(new StepItemWriteListener())
                .listener(new CustomChunkListener())
                .<PdadModel, PdadModel>chunk(2)
                .reader(pdadFileReader)
                .processor(pdadProcessor)
                .writer(pdadWriter)
                //.faultTolerant()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<PdadModel> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<PdadModel> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PdadModel>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
        
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] { 0, 1, 2});
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PdadModel> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PdadModel>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(PdadModel.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

}
```

Processor

```
public class PdadProcessors implements ItemProcessor<PdadModel, PdadModel>{
    
    private static final ILogger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdadProcessors.class);

    @Override
    public PdadModel process(PdadModel item) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Model Pdad {}", item.toString());
        // System.out.println("Inserting Pdad : " + item.toString());
            return item;
    }

}
```

Reading and writing for two chunks and not repeating for third chunks stuck in infinite loop.
why it is going in infinite loop?